# Excel Record Matching Two Sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Can't seem to figure this out.

I have two Excel sheets, A and B.

Sheet A has a column full of MLS IDs, call this column M and Sheet B has a column full of MLS IDs call this column N.

I would like to search Sheet A for the values from column N in the second sheet and where there is a match I would like to add a column O.

I have tried using VLOOKUP but afraid my formula doesn't work too well, and the extension .

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "Add a column O"? Do you mean, you want this formula to run down all of column O, and where there is a match, say "MATCH", or something like that? Could you show the vlookup you tried to use?

Comment: Provide an example please.

Comment: So basically when there is a match I want information to be added in a column in sheet A with the value 'Single Family' make sense?

Comment: Basically Sheet A has a column with IDs of students

Sheet B has a list of IDs of students who are late with an assignment

I want to search Sheet A for all the IDs of the students in Sheet B and add a column to those that matched with a column reading "Single Family" - for that row that matched IDs from Sheet A and B

Make sense?

Comment: That's not clear to me the way you are wording it. What do you mean "add a column"? Assume in sheet A you have student Bobby, in cell M2. In sheet B, Bobby shows up. So, you want O2 in sheet A to say "Single Family?"

Comment: Hi there that is pretty much correct.

If the value from Sheet B is found in Sheet A then "Single Family" is added in O2 in Sheet A

Answer (score 0):

If vlookup is failing, I would investigate using the index match method instead - it's very well documented online, and sidesteps most of the failings of lookups very nicely and efficiently. This link might help: http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/

Comment: If someone is struggling with vlookup, it is unlikely that simply saying "use index and match" will help them. First, try to determine why vlookup is failing - does the OP have poor syntax, or is vlookup not the right tool for the job?

Comment: Hence the edit with a link  I suspect vlookup probably isn't the correct tool in this case, and I found it very useful to get my head around using index match a few years ago when I was struggling with vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

There's a breakdown of how to use VLOOKUP here:

[How to combine two excels that have a common column (but aren't in the same order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544420/how-to-combine-two-excels-that-have-a-common-column-but-arent-in-the-same-orde/31545072#31545072)

A few common issues:
- Make sure the exact search string is actually in the search range (no leading whitespace, etc.)
- The search range needs to be anchored or it will drift and you will lose results
- the 4th argument (exact match) should be FALSE or you might get weird behavior